# Fetching data from API and react-router-dom on refresh / direct link

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm learning redux and routing and history with react-router-dom and react-connected-router for an app. I have an api and I do my fetchData in componentDidMount():

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { onFetchData, prodPerPage, currentPage, filters } = this.props;
    onFetchBooks(prodPerPage, currentPage, filters);
  }
```

In my pagination component I use a link that routes to the page which works fine onClick because I re-fetch data on click where currentPage becomes the pageIndex so data is fetched for that page.

Here is my link:

```
 <Link to={`/products/page/${item.page}`}>
   <PaginationItem {...item} />
 </Link>
```

Here is my route:

```
<Route exact path="/products/page/:page" component={ProductsPage} />
```

If I reload my page my currentPage is set to 1 from initialState.
On Back/Forward my page again loads data for page 1.

How can I set my currentPage to be whatever I navigate to? So if my link is *https://localhost:3000/products/page/3* then set currentPage to 3 and fetch the correct data?

Note: If I try to load *https://localhost:3000/products/page/3sddada* it doesn't redirect to 404, how do I fix that too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to get access to the dynamic pageid being passed into our route and use it to query the correct page from the API. This is easy to do using react-router-dom. The library passes in a prop called match into every route that is rendered. Inside this match object is another object called params. This holds all matching params where the key is the name we specified when creating the route and the value is the actual value in the URL.

```
 componentDidMount() {    
      const { page} = this.props.match.params;
      this.setState({currentPage:page});
      const { onFetchData, prodPerPage, filters } = this.props;
      onFetchBooks(prodPerPage, currentPage, filters);
      
    }
```

React-router v4 now allows you to use regexes to match params -- https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/products/page/:page(\\d+)" component={ProductsPage}/>
    <Route exact path="/products/page/:page(\\w+)" component={ErrorRedirectPage}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The only thing is that is not working though is the switch. Had to use path="/products/page/:page(\d+)" and then for error redirect path="*" and it works now.